# onclick editable text field using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Well, I am learning to create forms so I got this problem. I want a input field which will be simple text and when onclicking edit button it should be a input field. My link to work (https://codepen.io/TA0011/pen/XWBdbyW).

```
.wrapper-user{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    max-width: 800px;
    padding: 25px 40px 10px 40px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.wrapper-user form .form-row{
    display: flex;
    margin:  32px 0;
}
form .form-row  .input-box{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0 20px;
    position: relative;
}
.form-row button{
    margin-left:auto;
    color: #fff;
    background: #007bff;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding:5px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition:  all 0.4s ease;
    border: none;
    outline: none; 
}
.form-row .input-box input{
height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    outline: none;
    border:  none;
    padding:  0 30px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition:  all 0.3s ease;
}
.form-row .input-box p{
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css">
<div class="wrapper-user">
  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h2> First</h2>
    <div class="form-row">
                <div class="input-box">
                    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                    <input type="text" value="Umann">
                </div><button class="btn">Edit</button>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
                    <input type="email" Value="uxxxxxxgoxxxxx@gmail.com">
                </div>
      
                    <button class="btn">Edit</button>
            </div><!--form-row-->
    <h2>Second</h2>
    <div class="form-row">
                <div class="input-box">
                    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                    <p>Umann Goxxxxxxxx</p>
                </div>
      
                    <button class="btn">Edit</button>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
                    <p>UmannXXXXXXX@gmail.com</p>
                    
                </div>
      <button class="btn">Edit</button>
            </div><!--form-row-->
    
  </form>
</div>
```

Also my query is if we can write  but it should display as

. And on clicking edit button it should turn in editable textfield.

I tried contenteditable but I want in input form so that I can store the value in database.

Comment: Generic button on click submit form.... try to add type='button' on you edit button's

Comment: this question has been edited from codepen i.e. my work..... javascript part is wrong.

Comment: The codepen is not your? So post your complete code in [mcve] please

Comment: my codepen. but it shouldn't be posted here. because javascript is wrong there.

Comment: needed answer, if anyone can shall highly be obliged.

Comment: Explain better what is wrong

Comment: i explained,please provide answer to my query.

Comment: just add readonly to your input text field and remove it when click edit

Comment: can you provide the code? i didn't understand.

Comment: I'll propose you a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll propose you a little solution (for only the input fields).

1-Set the input field with `readonly` attribute and an unique `id`

2-Set to the `button` the data-edit attribute same as the id of input field you want to set editable

2.1 - Remember to set `type="button"` to prevent form submit

3- with js get all `buttons` with class `btn` and loop the collection

4- add a `listener` to each `button`

5- get the `data-edit` attribute of the clicked `button` to select the relative input

6-set `readonly` false

UPDATE:
When you click on edit button the attribute readonly is toggled and loses focus

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

buttons.forEach(item => {
      item.addEventListener('click', function(el) {
        let idInputAttibute = "#" + item.getAttribute('data-edit');
        let inputField = document.querySelector(idInputAttibute);
        inputField.readOnly ? (inputField.readOnly = false,inputField.focus()) :
                               inputField.readOnly = true
        
        ;
      });
    })
```

```css
.wrapper-user {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  max-width: 800px;
  padding: 25px 40px 10px 40px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.wrapper-user form .form-row {
  display: flex;
  margin: 32px 0;
}

form .form-row .input-box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.form-row button {
  margin-left: auto;
  color: #fff;
  background: #007bff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

.form-row .input-box input {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.form-row .input-box p {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css">
<div class="wrapper-user">
  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h2> First</h2>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="input-box">
        <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
        <input id="name" type="text" value="Umann" readonly>
      </div><button class="btn" type="button" data-edit="name">Edit</button>
      <div class="input-box">
        <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
        <input type="email" id="email" value="uxxxxxxgoxxxxx@gmail.com"  readonly>
      </div>

      <button class="btn" data-edit="email" type="button">Edit</button>
    </div>
    <!--form-row-->
    <h2>Second</h2>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="input-box">
        <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
        <p>Umann Goxxxxxxxx</p>
      </div>

      <button class="btn">Edit</button>
      <div class="input-box">
        <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
        <p>UmannXXXXXXX@gmail.com</p>

      </div>
      <button class="btn">Edit</button>
    </div>
    <!--form-row-->

  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: onclicking again it should go to readonly texts. Edit the code, and i'll accept answer.

Comment: do you mean after edit, or after clicking the button for the second time?

Comment: yes.... on clicking edit again it should show readonly texts without the border-bottom.

Comment: i have two query: 1) onclicking, edit line should be at the end of the  word.
2)edited line should have border-bottom of 2px. edit the code so that i can approve your answer.

Comment: `function(el)`? You mean: `function(ev)` ...

Comment: Also try always to use `buttons.forEach(handleItem)` instead of initializing all over again the same function code.

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan everything is correct in the answer one thing just, onclicking edit vertical bar appears in front of the letter of the word. it should be at the end of the letter of the word.

Comment: @UmannGoswami I'm not the author of this Answer

Comment: can you suggest an alternate option?

Comment: @Sfili_81 can you edit it again?